# Objective-C: Randomizer objectAtIndex Not sorting through All Types

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

So I have a "food" table that has three types: "Meals, Desserts, and Snacks". I have these categories attached to buttons in a Search Options page and they basically do a "Select * from food where type = 'Meals'" kind of thing and that works fine.

The problem is that when I try to randomly retrieve an object from "All" ("select * from food") it only returns meals.  I'm thinking it's a problem maybe with the "objectAtIndex:0"?

```
ranDom = [_entries bjl_shuffledArray];
        Place *p = [ranDom objectAtIndex:0];
```

So I tried to randomize the index as well:

```
NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random()%[_entries count];
        ranDom = [_entries bjl_shuffledArray];
        Place *p = [ranDom objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```

...but it still seems to only be retrieving results from Meals... not the other two types in "food".

Any idea how I can get it to better return results from all three types?

**EDIT: Here's how bjl_shuffled_array works:**

```
- (NSArray *)bjl_shuffledArray
{
    NSMutableArray *shuffledArray = [self mutableCopy];
    NSUInteger arrayCount = [shuffledArray count];

     if (arrayCount > 0) {
    for (NSUInteger i = arrayCount - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        NSUInteger n = arc4random_uniform(i + 1);
        [shuffledArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
     }
    return [shuffledArray copy];
}
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to confirm what exactly is in `ranDom` and `_entries`? I suspect that's probably the root of the problem.  You definitely shouldn't need to randomize the index if you've shuffled the array. Also `arc4random() % [_entries count] ` will crash with a div by zero error if your `entries` array is ever empty. Can you show the implementation of `bjl_shuffledArray`?

Comment: Added the code for bjl_shuffledarray.  I haven't been able to figure out how to log it properly.  RandomIndex... of course... gives me a random index (last one was 21). ranDom is a bit weirder... It gave me 30 entries out of the 300 available. Last one was: "<Place: 0x15687b80>", I used: NSLog(@"ranDom:%@", ranDom);  How do I proceed from here? And is there a way I can see exactly what's contained in that array?

Comment: The shuffled array method is ok.  As for the debug output, lldb sometimes truncates outpu - but you can be sure how many items there are in the array by logging its count i.e.:. `NSLog(@"%d",[array count]);`  Alternatively iterate over the array with a for loop and log each item individually - either by just logging the item or calling some method on it that will tell you what it is (Or use `NSStringFromClass([item class])`). I wonder if the problem is to do with how `_entries` is populated in the first place.

Comment: The odd thing is... for the other types (Meals, Snacks, etc...) it seems to work just fine... So why wouldn't "Select * from food" show all the types? The fact that I got 30 results makes me think there's some sort of a limit somewhere... And there you have it. There are 36 entries in the first category... but 31-36 never appear. That means that there's a limit of 30 somewhere in either the randomizer or in "_entries"... The hunt begins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the "_entries" was only returning 30 results.  I knew there had to be a limit somewhere because there should have been about 306 items.  First I checked through all the code of the app for the number "30" and found nothing.  So I checked through the PHP file and discovered that someone had snuck in this:

```
$rows_per_page = 30;
```

Changed "30" to "3000" and now all is right with the world. Thank you Rich Tolley for your help.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help